# Why i'm getting exception Unable to find an entry point when using SendMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to send some text to the notepad window.

In the top of form1:

```
const int WM_SETTEXT = 0X000C;

//include FindWindowEx
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

//include SendMessage
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessages(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
```

Then in the constructor:

```
//getting notepad's process | at least one instance of notepad must be running
Process notepadProccess = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];

//getting notepad's textbox handle from the main window's handle
//the textbox is called 'Edit'
IntPtr notepadTextbox = FindWindowEx(notepadProccess.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
//sending the message to the textbox
SendMessages(notepadTextbox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "This is the new Text!!!");
```

The exception is on the line:

```
SendMessages(notepadTextbox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "This is the new Text!!!");
```

An unhandled exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in exe

Additional information: Unable to find an entry point named 'SendMessages' in DLL 'user32.dll'.

The full exception message:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233053
  Message=Unable to find an entry point named 'SendMessages' in DLL 'user32.dll'.
  Source=Grads_Scripts
  TypeName=""
  StackTrace:
       at Grads_Scripts.Form1.SendMessages(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 uMsg, Int32 wParam, String lParam)
       at Grads_Scripts.Form1..ctor() in D:\C-Sharp\Form1.cs:line 142
       at Grads_Scripts.Program.Main() in D:\C-Sharp\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: you should inspect the dll to verify the funcion name called `SendMessages`.. I find it rare it being plural 'cause that funciont most likely send one message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, no such function exists.

You mean `SendMessage`.

Comment: And if i want to sendmessage instead to notepad to another visual studio opened project ? If i have a opened project with a window of a class for example test.cs and i want to send message to the visual studio of this window like i'm typing inside the visual studio. Possible ?